# Rename a folder with node.js after reading it with readdirSync. But permissions are denied

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a personal node.js file management system.

The program has to be able to read all the folders within a folder, and compare them to a list. If the folders aren't located in that list they are moved into a new directory.

For example the list will be:

```
folder1, folder2, folder3
```

And the Directory Tree looks like this

```
              mainFolder
    _____________|_____________
   |        |      |           |
folder1   folder2  folder3   folder4
```

In this case "folder4" is not in the list and should be moved.

I am using the fs.readdirSync command in node.js to store folders into an array like this:

```
var foldersInDirectory= []; //my storage array
fs.readdirSync(mainFolder).forEach(file => {
  foldersInDirectory.push(file);
});
```

Then I do some code to compare my list to the array, and whatever isn't in the list I attempt to move. In the code below I just use the name "folder4" for simplicity.

```
fs.rename('folder4', 'newFolder', function(err) {
    if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
});
```

However I get a permissions error. After some research I found out that the error comes from the folder being open. So I tried to reverse the code and perform the "rename" function first. This worked perfectly, however for my real world code to work I have to be able to compare the folders to my list before moving folders around.

Is there a command to close the "folder4" after I am done adding it to my list. Or make nginx release it so that it can be renamed?

I tried things like putting the rename function in a set timeout function but that didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Okay well I didn't find a solution to the problem directly, but I did find a work around.

The remove directory command still fires in node.js even after being read.

So I copied all the contents of the directory I wanted to move into an array.

I then ran this command to delete the directory:

```
fs.rmdir('folder4', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('successfully deleted directory');
});
```

And using the array I made earlier I remake the directory in it's destination folder. Seems like kind of a work around, and I hope there's an easier way, but this did work for me.

If anyone has any other suggestions/feedback please let me know thank you!